# WinRT C# screenshot of AppBar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I am using "RenderTargetBitMap" class to take screenshot in WinRT C# xaml application as explained in this great article: 
http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2013/11/05/render-the-screen-of-a-windows-store-app-to-a-bitmap-in-windows-8-1/comment-page-1/#comment-354935

Here is code snippet to take capture screen.

```
async Task<RenderTargetBitmap> CaptureToStreamAsync(FrameworkElement uielement, IRandomAccessStream stream, Guid encoderId)
{
 try
{
  var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
  await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(uielement);

  var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

  var logicalDpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
  var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, stream);
  encoder.SetPixelData(
      BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
      BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
      (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
      (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
      logicalDpi,
      logicalDpi,
      pixels.ToArray());

  await encoder.FlushAsync();

  return renderTargetBitmap;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  DisplayMessage(ex.Message);
  }

   return null;
}
```

It works great for any Framework elements inside page or for entire page. But fails with below error for AppBar elements or entire appbar:

*A first chance exception of type ‘System.ArgumentException’ occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.*

Note: AppBar is visible when trying to take SS.

How can I overcome the above exception? or Is there a better way to take SS of Appbars?